# Basemap m.scatter not allowing points to appear on map and retain fillcontinents color

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have this Python code:

```py
m = Basemap(projection='tmerc',
            llcrnrlon=-10.56,
            llcrnrlat=51.39,
            urcrnrlon=-5.34,
            urcrnrlat=55.43,
            resolution='h',
            epsg=29902)

# Fill the globe with blue color
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')

# Draw country boundaries
m.drawcountries()

# Fill the continents with the land color
m.fillcontinents(color='coral', lake_color='aqua')

m.drawcoastlines()

lons = [-7.637558, -5.926437, -6.266155]
lats = [54.350155, 54.607868, 53.350140]

x, y = m(lons, lats)

m.scatter(x, y, marker='D', color='m')

plt.show()
```

When I run it the points don't appear on my map. If I add `zorder=0` to `fillcontinents` they do appear but the entire map is `aqua` color. If I don't have `zorder=0` and I use `m.plot` instead of `m.scatter` the points are plotted but the lines appear between them whic I don't want.

How do I get the points to appear on their own but retain the `fillcontinents` color?

**Possible Solution**

I added `zorder=2` to `m.scatter`. Is this the most Pythonic way to do this?

```py
m = Basemap(projection='tmerc',
            llcrnrlon=-10.56,
            llcrnrlat=51.39,
            urcrnrlon=-5.34,
            urcrnrlat=55.43,
            resolution='h',
            epsg=29902)

# Fill the globe with blue color
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')

# Draw country boundaries
m.drawcountries()

# Fill the continents with the land color
m.fillcontinents(color='coral', lake_color='aqua')

m.drawcoastlines()

lons = [-7.637558, -5.926437, -6.266155]
lats = [54.350155, 54.607868, 53.350140]

x, y = m(lons, lats)

m.scatter(x, y, marker='D', color='m', zorder=2)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `zorder=2` to `m.scatter`. Is this the most Pythonic way to do this?

```py
m = Basemap(projection='tmerc',
            llcrnrlon=-10.56,
            llcrnrlat=51.39,
            urcrnrlon=-5.34,
            urcrnrlat=55.43,
            resolution='h',
            epsg=29902)

# Fill the globe with blue color
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')

# Draw country boundaries
m.drawcountries()

# Fill the continents with the land color
m.fillcontinents(color='coral', lake_color='aqua')

m.drawcoastlines()

lons = [-7.637558, -5.926437, -6.266155]
lats = [54.350155, 54.607868, 53.350140]

x, y = m(lons, lats)

m.scatter(x, y, marker='D', color='m', zorder=2)

plt.show()
```